# which are the must visit daily websites for joomla Developers?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have need to develop my joomla knowledge,so please Guide me which are the must visit daily websites for joomla Developers? other then Stack OverFlow.

Comment: That’s subjective and does not belong on stackoverflow. Check the FAQ on what to ask here, and what not to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I would categorize as must “visit” daily websites for joomla devs is the vulnerabilities and extension vulnerabilities lists. Nothing else is day-important. But that may be fit more for webmasters than devs.

For improving joomla knowledge, don’t visit daily sites but develop and check the wiki. There’s guides there that will help you.